# convert the string from combobox to double

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to do the following:

```
CCombobox m_obs;
CString temp;

m_obs.GetWindowTextA(temp);
double newObs = strtod(temp, NULL);
```

However, I get the error in `strtod()` that no suitable conversion function from `CString` to `const char *` exists.

How do I convert the string from combobox to double?

Comment: this should work unless you have UNICODE enabled in your project, in which case you need to convert your string to ANSI first

Comment: @aleguna Sounds like an answer.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers. My project is UNICODE. I changed it to to both Not Set and also Multi-Byte Character set, but then I get build error `LNK1561: entry point must be defined`.

Comment: @chintans: for Multi-Byte Character set you have to have a `wmain` instead of `main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your replies.

For UNICODE projects, do the following:

```
double NewObs = wcstod(temp, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try instead `CStringA`, to force use of the Ansi version otherwise CString is dependent on the compiler switch where UNICODE is default.

Answer (score 1):

`strtod()` expect `const char * str` for the first argument.
You should do:

```
const char* cstr = (LPCTSTR)temp;
double newObs = strtod(cstr, NULL);
```

Comment: CString has an implicit conversion operator to `LPCTSTR` the fact that compiler didn't pick it up means that OP's project has UNICODE enabled and `LPCTSTR` is a wide char string. Which means `const char* cstr = (LPCTSTR)temp;` won't work either

Comment: Many thanks for the answers. My project is UNICODE. I changed it to to both Not Set and also Multi-Byte Character set, but then I get build error LNK1561: entry point must be defined.